# How to find one record through another without strict relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models **Crew** and **Clients**

I can create them independently.

Crew has property `client_project` which is

```
=form_for(@crew)do |f|
  =f.select(:client_project, @clients.map(&:project)
```

where `@clients = Client.all`and `@crew = Crew.find_by(params[:id])`

**Question:**

After creation of the `Crew` item, how can I show `Client` with project which was selected for particular Crew?

In rails console I've tried variations of:

```
crew = Crew.first
client = Client.find_by(project: crew.client_project)
```

but with no result

Comment: what's their relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `crew` has `client_project` and `client` just has `project`.

If this is the case, you should be able to do (assuming `crew` is a valid object):

```
clients = Client.where(project: crew.client_project)
```

This would return a collection of Clients, since it doesn't sound like you've defined the relationships in the AR models (which you should probably do in order to make this easier)